# How to switch from H2 database to Postgres in jBPM default application?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jbpm

I need to switch from H2 database to Postgres in the default jBpm application generated in https://start.jbpm.org.
I tried to change the properties file with one given *application-postgres.propreties*, saved the file, then run `mvn clean install -U` the I launch the application  `.\launch.bat clean install`.
It returns this exception.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's means the application was not able to create the database, even thoughI set it on update mode.

````
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.company.service.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[business-application-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[business-application-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[business-application-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[business-application-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/jbpm/springboot/datasources/JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create XADataSource instance from 'org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create XADataSource instance from 'org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create XADataSource instance from 'org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource'
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSourceInstance(JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:139) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSource(JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:126) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:68) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d82c7bfc.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d82c7bfc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3cf69439.invoke(<generated>) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d82c7bfc.dataSource(<generated>) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[business-application-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:277) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSourceInstance(JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:133) ~[jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources-7.33.0.Final.jar!/:7.33.0.Final]
        ... 54 common frames omitted ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line on the stacktrace suggests you're missing Postgres jdbc driver in the app.

If you pay close attention to the pom.xml file in your business-application-service folder, the driver will only be loaded if you activate postgres profile.

As you already changed the properties file, you might be only missing the `-P postgres`  parameter when you launch your application.

It should be something like

```
.\launch.bat clean install -P postgres
```